# OpenSSL::Cipher::CipherError: unsupported on github CI

Tags: ruby, github, ssl, openssl, aes

I am trying to encrypt a short string with fast symetric alghorithm (security is not important). I just need short encrypted strings.

```
def encrypt(msg)
  KEY = "346x4".freeze
  ALGORITHM = "rc2-40-cbc".freeze
  cipher = OpenSSL::Cipher.new(ALGORITHM)
  cipher.encrypt 
  cipher.key = KEY
  crypt = cipher.update(msg.to_s) + cipher.final
  crypt_string = Base64.encode64(crypt)
  crypt_string.rstrip
end
```

This works on development but fails on Github CI with error:

```
OpenSSL::Cipher::CipherError: unsupported
```

I ran (on Github CI):

```
OpenSSL::Cipher.ciphers
```

And got list of supported algorithms:

```
["aes-128-cbc","aes-128-cbc-hmac-sha1","aes-128-cbc-hmac-sha256","aes-128-ccm","aes-128-cfb","aes-128-cfb1","aes-128-cfb8","aes-128-ctr","aes-128-ecb","aes-128-gcm","aes-128-ocb","aes-128-ofb","aes-128-xts","aes-192-cbc","aes-192-ccm","aes-192-cfb","aes-192-cfb1","aes-192-cfb8","aes-192-ctr","aes-192-ecb","aes-192-gcm","aes-192-ocb","aes-192-ofb","aes-256-cbc","aes-256-cbc-hmac-sha1","aes-256-cbc-hmac-sha256","aes-256-ccm","aes-256-cfb","aes-256-cfb1","aes-256-cfb8","aes-256-ctr","aes-256-ecb","aes-256-gcm","aes-256-ocb","aes-256-ofb","aes-256-xts","aes128","aes128-wrap","aes192","aes192-wrap","aes256","aes256-wrap","aria-128-cbc","aria-128-ccm","aria-128-cfb","aria-128-cfb1","aria-128-cfb8","aria-128-ctr","aria-128-ecb","aria-128-gcm","aria-128-ofb","aria-192-cbc","aria-192-ccm","aria-192-cfb","aria-192-cfb1","aria-192-cfb8","aria-192-ctr","aria-192-ecb","aria-192-gcm","aria-192-ofb","aria-256-cbc","aria-256-ccm","aria-256-cfb","aria-256-cfb1","aria-256-cfb8","aria-256-ctr","aria-256-ecb","aria-256-gcm","aria-256-ofb","aria128","aria192","aria256","bf","bf-cbc","bf-cfb","bf-ecb","bf-ofb","blowfish","camellia-128-cbc","camellia-128-cfb","camellia-128-cfb1","camellia-128-cfb8","camellia-128-ctr","camellia-128-ecb","camellia-128-ofb","camellia-192-cbc","camellia-192-cfb","camellia-192-cfb1","camellia-192-cfb8","camellia-192-ctr","camellia-192-ecb","camellia-192-ofb","camellia-256-cbc","camellia-256-cfb","camellia-256-cfb1","camellia-256-cfb8","camellia-256-ctr","camellia-256-ecb","camellia-256-ofb","camellia128","camellia192","camellia256","cast","cast-cbc","cast5-cbc","cast5-cfb","cast5-ecb","cast5-ofb","chacha20","chacha20-poly1305","des","des-cbc","des-cfb","des-cfb1","des-cfb8","des-ecb","des-ede","des-ede-cbc","des-ede-cfb","des-ede-ecb","des-ede-ofb","des-ede3","des-ede3-cbc","des-ede3-cfb","des-ede3-cfb1","des-ede3-cfb8","des-ede3-ecb","des-ede3-ofb","des-ofb","des3","des3-wrap","desx","desx-cbc","id-aes128-CCM","id-aes128-GCM","id-aes128-wrap","id-aes128-wrap-pad","id-aes192-CCM","id-aes192-GCM","id-aes192-wrap","id-aes192-wrap-pad","id-aes256-CCM","id-aes256-GCM","id-aes256-wrap","id-aes256-wrap-pad","id-smime-alg-CMS3DESwrap","rc2","rc2-128","rc2-40","rc2-40-cbc","rc2-64","rc2-64-cbc","rc2-cbc","rc2-cfb","rc2-ecb","rc2-ofb","rc4","rc4-40","rc4-hmac-md5","seed","seed-cbc","seed-cfb","seed-ecb","seed-ofb","sm4","sm4-cbc","sm4-cfb","sm4-ctr","sm4-ecb","sm4-ofb"]
```

The list **includes**: `rc2-40-cbc`. Why is exception thrown?

Answer (score 1):

On modern versions of Ubuntu, there's a legacy provider which contains obsolete algorithms.  RC2 with a 40-bit key is considered obsolete, because the U.S. no longer has export controls requiring weak keys like that and has not for well over a decade.  As a result, these algorithms see extremely little use because there are much more secure, much faster algorithms available.

On Ruby 3.3 with OpenSSL 3.0, you can load the legacy provider to use this algorithm:

```
ruby -r openssl -e 'OpenSSL::Provider.load("legacy")'
```

Otherwise, you'll need to modify the system OpenSSL configuration file.

Note that in any case, you must have a unique and unpredictable IV for every CBC encryption, which you don't have, or there is no security whatever.  That will add at least 64 bits to the length of your data.  In general, every mode but ECB requires an IV of some sort, which you'll have to include and which will need to be unique.

If your goal is simply to convert short strings to uninvertable strings, you don't need to decrypt, and you can deal with the possibility of duplicates, you may simply choose to use a hash function like SHA-256 and truncate it to your desired length.  SHA-256 is available in hardware on modern machines and will be extremely fast.

Comment: Why is then `OpenSSL::Cipher.ciphers` returning `rc2-40-cbc` if it is not really supported? I need to decrypt data. My primary goal is to convert id-s into more random strings which should be short because they will be part of URL. Id-s are visible elsewhere anyway. We just don't want it exposed in URL.

Comment: It's supported because OpenSSL has compiled support for it.  It's just not enabled by default and is stored in an alternate provider because you shouldn't be using it.

Comment: `ruby -r openssl -e 'OpenSSL::Provider.load("legacy")'` should I run this only once or every time when server is restarted? (I use Rails and I do not know how can I run this operation on e.g. Heroku)

Comment: `OpenSSL::Provider.load("legacy")` needs to be in your regular code before you call any of your code that uses the legacy provider. The startup code for your server would probably be the right place.

Answer (score 0):

Since security is not a prime concern and and openssl is removing support for less secure algorithms I went further with another implementation:

https://github.com/sqids/sqids-ruby

Which generates even nicer results.